# Understanding battery label

Tags: battery-charging

I am currently learning how to read the specifications on a battery label (primary cells - non rechargeable)

I came across a new battery with the following specification

> **Voltage:** DC 5 V - DC 9 V Intelligent output; **Rated Power:** 25 W; **Capacity:** 200000 mAh; **Energy:** 300 Wh.

Based on my current understanding, the battery will have:

- Max output power: 25 W
- Max output current: 2.5 .. 5 A (depending on voltage)
- Total capacity: 200,000 mAh

(a) Am I correct?

(b) What does this 300 Wh tell me?

My understanding is that a 200,000 mAh will have equivalent capacity of 1 kWh at 5 V, with an imaginary 100% efficiency. This is far from the written 300 Wh so there must be something wrong with my understanding.

Comment: 200,000mAh means that it can provide (in theory) 200A for one hour, or 100A for 2 hours, or 400A for 0.5 hours, etc. Watt-hours is the same thing, except with watts because instead of taking into account just current, it takes into account both voltage and current. I don't see anything wrong with your understanding, but take battery labels with a grain of salt. It's possible the 300Wh was measured under high draw compared to the other ratings or takes into account voltage drop as the battery discharges or maybe they just didn't care.

Comment: @DKNguyen sorry i miswritten 200,000 mAh with 80,000 mAh - Edited. I understand enough that part, however it doesn't explain the 300WH part in product parameter

Comment: The "Voltage: DC5V-DC9V Intelligent output"implies to me that this is a "power pack" - a battery with attached DC-DC converter to provide the variable output voltage, not just a battery.  The mAh rating should have a voltage specified.

Comment: @PeterBennett I see. How about the written 300WH? (if it's power pack)

Comment: What kind of battery is this and is this from a reputable manufacturer? Do you have a link to the specifications? 200Ah is a large capacity and this must be a substantial device in any current battery technology. OTOH, if this is a cheap device from an unknown manufacturer, chances are that in reality, this device does not have nearly as much capacity as stated.

Comment: 300Wh and 200Ah * 5V tells you all you need to know ... about the trustworthiness of the specs on what you hopefully aren't buying.

Comment: @user_1818839  Do you know Peukert's Law?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **(a) Am I correct?**

Almost, the Ah is lifetime primary self-recharge capacity = 200 Ah / N , N=number of self-charge cycles = **TBD Ah**

> Voltage: DC 5 V - DC 9 V Intelligent output; Rated Power: 25 W; Capacity: 200000 mAh; Energy: 300 Wh.

***The Ah and Wh capacities are the lifetime ratings,** somewhat like comparing 500 cycles of a Li-Ion call with a 2500 mAh rating in 20h at 3.6V mean is   9Wh x 500 = 4.5 kWh maximum energy storage capacity or 1.25 kAh charge lifetime.*

> **(b) What does this 300 Wh tell me?**

> Energy: 300 Wh.

It means one slow discharge cycle e.g. 3W in 100h between 9 and 5V.

### Thought experiment for parameter:

E: \$V\cdot I\cdot t(s) (*3600s/h)= 300 ~Wh_{rated} = 1.08 MJ/3600[s/h]\$
5V: \$P=25W = 5V \cdot  5A ,~  R_{L}=\dfrac{5V}{5A} = 1 \Omega ~min., 300Wh/5V =60Ah ~?\$
C: \$t=300Wh/25W=1.2h, C= 5A \cdot 1.2h = *6Ah*\$
t=20h: \$P=15W= 5V\cdot 3A ,R_L= 5V/3A=1.67 \Omega\$
\$~But~only N = 200Ah/60Ah = 3.33~ ~ life~ cycles\$

9V: \$V^2/P=R = 9V^2/25W=3.24 ~\Omega ~min\$
\$~~~~~~~~300 Wh/ 25 W = 12 h , ~C= Wh/V= 300/9~=~*33.3Ah*\$   5x more aH   and \$N=200Ah/33.3 = 6\$full life charge cycles, so reducing load power greatly extends life power cycles in V*Ah.

[Peukert's Law](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Peukert%27s_law) suggests capacity drops when using max power for time << 20 h from heat rise but k factor is unknown.

### misc.

The Lithium-cobalt electrodes and electrolyte must also be externally charged, unlike the **Al-Air ion** cells which are organic chemical + water + air self-charging fuel cells. (AFAIK)

The organic ESR will limit the self recharge time which is not given nor is the single-cycle energy density or the number of charge lifecycles.

The degradation over time is also a factor, but the organic recharge process requires no external charger, except time for the chemical process to self-recharge.

How long can use 25W before it decays to 0. Is it 12 h or less, unless you ask for more specifications and maintenance requirements to achieve lifetime Ah rating or 200 Ah.  I would use the conservative timer load but then the recharge time is TBD to get back to 9V.

This fuel cell needs frequent maintenance with freshwater (deionized? desalinated? distilled? tap ?) and then less frequent graphite anode replacement and at end of life resell/recycle the alum. oxide sludge in the bottom. But details are missing from this supplier thru Alibaba.

### Lifetime estimate

No charging this (1) battery 200 Ah*5V = 1 kWh vs ~ 1.25kWh for a 18650 Li Ion (2) thus (1) requires no electric charger but needs water and anode replacement to achieve full lifespan. but (2) requires a smart charger.

(1) is 9V no load and 5V at full load 25W and some (?) smart algorithm for max-current (OCP) and under-voltage (UVP) so maybe not a constant regulated voltage battery.

This is an Aluminum (Al) Graphite (C) Air battery with some Potassium Nitrate oxidizer and a liquid organic dielectric. This [AL-AIR battery is a new "fuel-cell" technology.](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Aluminium%E2%80%93air_battery) It maybe not ready for prime-time but is a merging new technology. I suggest get extra graphite anodes and deionized water.(maybe?)

[image] [ref](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s41918-020-00065-4)

### Assumptions on battery source

Emergency 2000000mAh 25W Small Emergency Generator
Product Details:
Place of Origin:    CHINA
Brand Name: SEIRIOS
Certification:  CE, FCC
Model Number:   GS001
[image]
http://www.battery-generator.com/sale-13528939-emergency-2000000mah-25w-small-emergency-generator.html

### Added

After watching a video from the supplier,the fuel cell supplies immediate max storage capacity after installing the kit of powdered electrolyte and accelerant , then special bags of water then anode plates.  This is by cost reasons, an emergency use battery due to cost/kWh total. Thus total use cycles of full DoC is limited.

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: I found then researched supplier technology and similar AL-graphite batteries  @hobbs et al

Comment: What supplier? There's no info in the question.

Comment: Google the specs and find it on Alibaba

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 thank you for detailed explanation. However i might missed some of your point, you were saying 300WH listed means **REAL capacity** in "slow discharge cycle e.g. 3W in 100h between 9 and 5V" because of Peukerts law? (reduced from 1000 WH capacity in 5V) - I don't initially assume Peukerts applied here since it's not lead acid in nature

Comment: Or does it means 300WH capacity when maximum power (25W) being used?

Comment: battery makers will always spec 20h rates unless there is a rate that yields more Wh.  One cannot assume it has more like 1000Wh but Peukert's Law applies to all batteries but k is different for each type and depends on the ESR and self heating I believe but also the memory capacity above Float voltage or energy stored during CV mode charging.

Comment: Did you notice the question concerned non-rechargable primaries?

Comment: @ScottSeidman  Yes All primaries are by definition "non-rechargeable" , but this is a fuel cell, so recharging is done chemically with maintenance until the anodes are depleted.  But capacity is still a function of the rate of power consumption to maximum for Peukert's Law. What are you implying was incorrect in my answer?

Comment: The definition you gave for Ah -- which is simply the battery lifetime for one charge.

Comment: Does it state unambiguously that it is for one charge? It doesn't seem to for Wh. what would you change in my answer? @ScottSeidman